# Integral convergence test $\int_{0}^5 \frac{1}{(x^p-1)^{1/3}}dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

For which values of the real parameter p does the following integral converge?
$$\int_{0}^5 \frac{1}{(x^p-1)^{1/3}}dx$$

Sorry for not showing any attempts, but I just have no idea what to do here.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by $i=0$?

Comment: Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

near $1$,

$$x^p-1=e^{p\ln (x)}-1\sim p\ln (x) $$

Comment: X=1 is a problematic point. How do you handle it?